# Where to book Henn-na Hotel Maihama

Tags: online-resources, japan, bookings, hotels, tokyo

[Henn-na is opening a second robot hotel this month](https://www.travelvoice.jp/english/the-second-henn-na-hotel-served-by-robots-will-open-in-maihama-close-to-tokyo-disney-resort-in-2017/). I can only find details about booking the original Henn-na Hotel in Nagasaki on [their website](http://h-n-h.jp), is there somewhere I can make a booking for the hotel near Tokyo?

Comment: Please include a link to what you are referring to by "their website".

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the [hotels website](http://www.h-n-h.jp/maihama/) there is a link to the page where you can [book rooms](https://advance.reservation.jp/hnhmaihama/stay_pc/rsv/index.aspx?hi_id=1&lang=ja-JP). The page only exists in Japanese though, but it's usable with Google Translate. Due to high demand the hotel doesn't accept bookings via other methods such as e-mail or via phone.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the hotel in Maihama has a [separate webpage](http://www.hennnahotelmaihamatokyobay.com/en-gb/).